# Correctly reference jQuery in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Encountered such problem: I`ve created a new blank project of ASP.NET MVC site. Then I`m trying to add a reference to jquery-1.3.2.js from Masterpage head. But in this case, page doesn`t loading to browser. I`ve bee trying  and src="<%=Url.Content ("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js") %>", all the same. Then I moved the script reference to the end of the , and the page began to load. But i need to use jQuery earlier, in ContentPlaceHolders. What is the problem?

Comment: Whats the error message?  "Doesn't loading to browser" means a lot of things.

Comment: No error message. Web development helper shows, that all HTML has been transfered in responce, but the page stops rendering in place, where I put the reference to jQuery

Comment: I`m very very sorry! I`m an idiot. I`ve typed <script blah.. /> instead of <script blah.. ></script>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to insert it into the head of the master page reference it.

have you tried just hard coding the source value?

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

of course your path may be different...

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Should work though...

Comment: can you reference any javascript in that folder.... Experiment.  Create a small js file with say an alert function and see if the code can reference it and does the same or works.  If it works, I would maybe re-download jquery.

Comment: I`m very very sorry! I`m an idiot. I`ve typed <script blah.. /> instead of <script blah.. ></script>

Comment: After my mistake, your solution looks most colose to be right

Answer (score 1):

Why not reference teh jquery on the [google](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jquery) or [Microsoft](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/09/16/microsoft-ajax-cdn-and-the-jquery-validation-library.aspx) cdn ?

From you master page is a good place to do this, correct syntax in links.

Comment: @jfar it's better for performance unless you happen to deploy to a cdn yourself.  quicker for browser to download if not already cached

Comment: this site is used in Intranet

Answer (score 0):

I think based on the way a blank project is made using the default project template for ASP.NET MVC you'd need it to do this:

```
src="<%=Url.Content ("~/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js") %>"
```

All resources are put in the Content folder by default, unless you've changed that or I'm just remembering incorrectly.

Either way, when the page renders check the html source and see what the src attribute gets evaluated to, and make sure that's correct.  I had the same problem once and that's what it turned out to be.

Comment: There is a Scripts folder in blank project. I`ve been trying to use Url.Content, but all the same.